# UWP package data folder is not normal

Tags: uwp, appdata

I'm publishing a few uwp apps, in the data folder "C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Packages", all my other app folder name are good, except the first one.

I know this is the Package Family Name, but why not use my app name?

@Microsoft

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does the app work?

Comment: Yes, it works, https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9pdsns7x9st9 . But I'm a obsessive-compulsive, LOL.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I want to change "26607hupo376787live.cn.511881C77D695_w694crywxda64" to 26607hupo376787live.cn.WeRecognition_w694crywxda64. But this is generated by Microsoft。 At the same time, my other apps package name are normal. I want to know why.